# nsprintoperation - check what user has selected

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pdf, printing

with this code i can print a pdf file:

```
let dictDocuments = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
let completePath = dictDocuments.appendingPathComponent("test.pdf")
let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: completePath!)

let printInfoDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: NSPrintInfo.shared().dictionary())
printInfoDict.setObject(NSPrintSpoolJob, forKey: NSPrintJobDisposition as NSCopying)
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printInfoDict as! [String : Any])
printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true
printInfo.scalingFactor = 1.5


let printOp = pdfDocument!.printOperation(for: printInfo, scalingMode: .pageScaleNone, autoRotate: true)!
printOp.runModal(for: self.view.window!, delegate: self, didRun: nil, contextInfo: nil)
```

can i check, which button the user has selected in the print panel ? (cancel or print)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsprintoperation/1532065-runmodal)

> The method specified by the `didRunSelector` parameter must have the following signature:
>
> ```
> func printOperationDidRun(_ printOperation NSPrintOperation, success: Bool, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
> ```
>
> The value of success is `true` if the print operation ran to completion without cancellation or error, and `false` otherwise.
>
> If you send `canSpawnSeparateThread` to an `NSPrintOperation` object with an argument of `true`, then the delegate specified in a subsequent invocation of `runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:` may be messaged in that spawned, non-main thread.

Comment: yes i road this doc. but i does not know how to use it :(

Comment: Rather than `... didRun: nil ... ` pass a `selector` `... didRun: #selector(printOperationDidRun(_:success:contextInfo:)` and implement the method.

Comment: ah okay, thanks. i tried `didRun: printOperation...` but the "selector way" was new for me

Answer (score 1):

for swift 5.1:

```
// prepare printOp
...

{
        //was: printOp.run()

        if let w = NSApp.mainWindow{
            let selector = #selector(printOperationDidRun(printOperation: success: contextInfo:))
            printOp.runModal(for: w, delegate: self,
                             didRun: selector,
                             contextInfo: nil)
        }
    }

    // apple docs:
    // - (void)printOperationDidRun:(NSPrintOperation *)printOperation  success:(BOOL)success  contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo

     @objc func printOperationDidRun( printOperation: NSPrintOperation,
                                      success: Bool,
                                      contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?){
        // use callback..

    }
```